# How to set default value of Card in mui

Tags: material-ui

I'm using this code in MUI for drawing Card.

```
    <Card {...props}>
      <CardHeader title="test" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} />
      <Divider />
      <CardContent>
        <Doughnut data={data} options={options} />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
```

But sometimes, the data value can be empty, and the card will be blank. Who can help me, how can I set the default value of the Card if the data is empty? Like `NoRowsOverlay` on `DataGrid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Card {...props}>
  <CardHeader title="test" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} />
  <Divider />
  <CardContent>
    {
       data ? (
        <Doughnut data={data} options={options} />
       ) : (
        <NoRowsOverlay />
       )
    }
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

You can change `data ?` to whatever true/false check you need to make. Also you probably need to change `<NoRowsOverlay />` to some other component you want to display instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `??`. For example: `data={data ?? 'defaultValue'}`.